# How to implement search with $nin

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using this `$nin` query for `$regex` search but it does not work:

```
first_name: { $nin: [ "/^rahul/i", "/^Bhosale/i" ] }
```

With this query execution, I was unable to find a result without "rahul" or "bhosale" but when I hit this query like below

```
first_name: { $nin: [ /^rahul/i, /^Bhosale/i ] }
```

it works fine.

when I pass an array to `find()` I think it takes the backslash with double quotes that why it was unable to find a result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit, do you mean you have an input array like `[ "/^rahul/i", "/^Bhosale/i" ]` or `[ "rahul", "Bhosale" ]` that you need to pass to the `find()` function with the `$nin` and you want to convert that array into a query object like `{ $nin: [ /^rahul/i, /^Bhosale/i ] }`?

Comment: I guess you are trying to pass an array of regex string to the query, or do you mean that when you pass the array into query, it gets converted into String from regex expression? Basically it needs an array of regex otherwise if there is a string it would try to look for exact matches. I am not sure about PHP, but there must be a way to create an array of regex rather than regex strings.

Comment: yes chridam,i want to array to find function but internally its array will encode the array  and encoded array will take backslash   [ "\/^rahul\/i", "\/^Bhosale\/i" ] that query will not return any result

Comment: yes rahul kumar...but how can not in condition in array of regex in mongo db query..